# how to refresh the contents of a particular component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.5

I have a splitbutton and an overlaypanel attached to splitbutton.

OverlayPanel is holding its previous values.

How do i refresh the contents of overlaypanel when the splitbutton is clicked

```
enter code here


            <p:splitButton 
                value="some value"
                id="splitbutton">
            </p:splitButton>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:overlayPanel id="idPanel" for="splitbutton" hideEffect="fade"  
            widgetVar="dropdownPanel" dynamic="true">
            <h:form id="ctTreeForm">
                <composite:page value="#{backingbean.value}"
                    id="ctTree" `enter code here`render="form:contentForm:splitbutton"
                    showFilter="false" onselect="dropdownPanel.hide()">
                </composite:page>
            </h:form>
        </p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: Show us relevant parts of your facelet code.

Comment: give to overlaypanel id and on your button use update="" attribute and give it the relative overlaypanel id.

Comment: Post your code to get some help.

Comment: @MohamedAli: thank u for reply...I tried ur suggestion but dint work

Comment: I posted the question because primefaces guide says "content of overlaypanel is cached so consecutive displays
do not load the content again. This feature is useful to reduce the page size and reduce page load
time."    I am a bit confused...